# How to gracefully abort yeoman generator on error?

Tags: yeoman

I'm writing a yeoman generator and want to check some prerequisites, for example a `git` being installed. I can easily check this using `.exec`, but how do i gracefully abort generator and report error to user? I searched docs, but it seems that i'm missing some obvious way to do it. Any hints?

Throwing exception will of course abort generator, but is it a best way? Maybe something more user friendly? Not all yeoman users are able to read js exceptions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### The current state of error handling in the popular generators is quite diverse:

- in the most cases they just log the error and return from the action and let the subsequnt actions run and return 0 status code:

  [generator-karma](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-karma/blob/405531a4aad03de0045235a9d4fd0b6284620f6b/app/index.js#L220-L226)'s `setupTravis` method:

  ```
  if (err) {
      this.log.error('Could not open package.json for reading.', err);
      done();
      return;
  ```

  }
- or set a custom `abort` property on error and skip further actions with cheking on the `abort` property but still return 0 status code:

  [generator-jhipster's](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/c0a735dafb80abcc8f56dfd49288ea106445fe46/cloudfoundry/index.js#L85-L97) CloudFoundryGenerator:

  ```
  CloudFoundryGenerator.prototype.checkInstallation = function checkInstallation() {
      if(this.abort) return;
      var done = this.async();

      exec('cf --version', function (err) {
          if (err) {
              this.log.error('cloudfoundry\'s cf command line interface is not available. ' +
          'You can install it via https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases');
              this.abort = true;
          }
          done();
      }.bind(this));
  };
  ```
- or manually end the process with `process.exit`:

  [generator-mobile](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-mobile/blob/29c5dbcb947f219c82eca200514788218bf26603/app/index.js#L84-L87)'s `configuring`method:

  ```
  if (err) {
        self.log.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
  }
  ```

However none of these methods provide a good way to signal to the environment that something went wrong except the last one but directly calling `process.exit` is a design smell.

Throwing an exception is also an option but this presents also the stackstrace to the user which is not always a good idea.

### The best option would be use the [Environment.error](http://yeoman.io/environment/Environment.html#error) method, which has some nice advantages:

- the `Environment` is exposed thorough the `env` property of the `yeoman.generators.Base`
- an `error` event is emitted which is handled by the yo cli code
- the execution will result in a non zero (error) status code which is override-able
- by default yo will display only the message and no stacktrace
- the stacktrace can be optionally displayed with providing the `--debug` built-in option when re-running the generator.

With using this technique your action method would look like this:

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  method1: function () {
    console.log('method 1 just ran');
    this.env.error("something bad is happened");
    console.log('this won't be executed');
  },
  method2: function () {
    console.log('this won't be executed');
  }
});
```

Comment: In my case I had to pass the error to the async function to keep the generator from completing successfully: `done("ERROR")`

Comment: The `this.env.error` method is awesome if want to quite exit the whole process. However, the `this.abort` method is the way to **skip** this current (sub)generator and continue other (sub)generators.

Comment: @JunleLi can you point me to some documentation/source code of the `abort` method? I cannot find it on github in the https://github.com/yeoman/generator repo....

Comment: @nemesv There is no magic and no abort method. That is a my local boolean variable. In the beginning of each loop function (prompting, install, etc.), check this variable, if it is true, directly return and do nothing.

Comment: Perfect! I'm just starting to dive into building custom Yeoman generators and I gotta say the API docs are somewhat lacking. The `env.error` method seems super important for flow control but I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere in the docs. Doing a site search for "env.error" doesn't seem to surface anything and it's not listed in the API docs.